# Calculation of focal length from images

Tags: camera

I'm trying to calculate the focal length of my lenses (I have 4 different lenses, I will call them lens 1, 2, 3, 4). I know the sensor size of the cameras (I'm using 2 different cameras) that I'm using, I know the object width, and I know working distance.

I'm using the following formula:

> ***f*** = focal length of width = (working distance * sensor width)/(object
>   width + sensor width)

I also used the same formula with a little change:

> ***f'*** = focal length of width = (working distance * sensor width)/object
>   width

The sensor sizes for my cameras are as follows:

> Model: 134MCU - 1/3" - 3,52 mm * 4,78 mm
>
> Model: 130CU - 1/4" - 2,75 mm * 3,64 mm

Here is the problem, I took several pictures with both cameras from a known working distance and I measured the image width (I've placed a ruler into the image scene). After that I've calculated the ***f*** and ***f'*** using the formulas given. After calculating he focal length, I've come up with several observations, which I think are inconsistent. The observations are as follows:

1. As the working distance increases calculated focal length for each lens converges to a certain value. I was expecting to calculate same ***f***, ***f'*** value for each working distance. Why is this happening? Is there any dependency on the working distance, or any limitation on working distance (like, for lense with focal length **f mm** working distance can't be less then **n**)?
2. I have 8 different imaging setups since I have 4 lenses and 2 cameras. The ***f***, ***f'*** values that are calculated using images taken with 134MCU are different than images taken with 130CU for lens 1 and lens 2. Calculated values for lens 3 and 4 are the same. Why this might be happening?

   - calculated **lens 1** values using **130CU** are around **1.6 mm**.
   - calculated **lens 2** values using **130CU** are around **2.4 mm**.
   - calculated **lens 3** values using **130CU** are around **2.8 mm**.
   - calculated **lens 4** values using **130CU** are around **3.6 mm**.
   - calculated **lens 1** values using **134MCU** are around **1.4 mm**.
   - calculated **lens 2** values using **134MCU** are around **2.2 mm**.
   - calculated **lens 3** values using **134MCU** are around **2.8 mm**.
   - calculated **lens 4** values using **134MCU** are around **3.6 mm**.
3. When I talked with my lens provider they told me that lens 1, 2, 3, 4 has focal lengths 2.1 mm, 2.5 mm, 2.8 mm, and 3.6 mm respectively. So, why doesn't my calculated values match with these? Is there anything wrong with my calculation?

The images that I used can be found in [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/14588321/image_set.zip). I would be very thankful if anyone could help.

Regards,

Güney Kayım

Comment: What do you call the "working distance"? To the sensor surface, or to the center of the lens? It is hard to believe that you can have a focal length of 1.6 mm on a 1/3" sensor - the distortions you would get towards the edges would be enormous. Remember that "real world optics" doesn't quite follow "paraxial formulas". Light doesn't travel through the optic in a straight line.

Comment: By "working distance" I meant the distance between the object and the lens. Actually distortions towards the edges are enormous. I believe that the focal length values that my provider told be is correct, but I can't figure out why I can't calculate it. Can it be because lens (2.1 mm and 2.5 mm) format is not appropriate for 1/3" and 1/4" sensors?

Comment: I think you are exactly right. See my updated answer.

Comment: My provider said they have a better lens now. And when I look at the images that he send  I can see that most of the distortion is gone but the image width is same. This does not match to your idea I guess? Or am I wrong?
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/14588321/distortion.zip

Comment: There is a difference between `distortion` and `focus`. The original images were both distorted and out of focus near the edge. In the new image you posted, the image is clearly more in focus at the edge, but the distortion is the same (a straight line becomes curved). An ideal ('pinhole') projection would leave straight lines straight - that's what your formula expects. Towards the center this is "more true".

Comment: Hmm.. Now everything is much more clear for me. Thank you very much. I might still have some more questions after I spend some time thinking about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just downloaded the images you posted, and the answer is staring us in the face.

The formula you are using is assuming that every ray of light travels in a straight line from the object to the sensor. In reality, these wide angle lenses have quite complex multiple surfaces, and the light is changing direction many times as it travels through the "stack". As a consequence, there is significant distortion towards the edges. The height of the lines on the ruler gets smaller towards the edges - where a "perfect pinhole camera" would have kept them all in exact proportion.

It is very hard to come up with an equation that properly accounts for this distortion - usually metrology applications of cameras (where people really care about these things) will do a geometrical calibration at the focal distance of interest to correct for it.

So the answer to your question "is there anything wrong with my calculation?" is this: "yes there is something wrong - your calculation is for an ideal system. You don't have an ideal system."

**EDIT** It occurred to me that you can do something rather better by using a "smaller sensor":

1. Take the images you already have
2. Look at a part of the image (near the center)
3. Find the distance in pixels between two markers on your ruler that span less than 10% of the sensor width
4. Compute the "apparent sensor size" = `(number of pixels between markers / number of pixels across sensor) * sensor width`
5. Use the apparent sensor size in your calculation

By using a variable number of pixels (that match an exact number of divisions on your ruler) you limit the amount of estimating / interpolating you have to do.  I think this will address most of the distortion problem and give you results consistent with the data from the manufacturer.

Comment: Ok, I have another question then. If I had a better lens (again with 2.1 mm focal length), which prevents distortion towards the edges, is my calculation going to be closer to ideal? This is the outcome I get from your response.

Comment: Yes - in fact, if you repeat the calculation for different fields of view, you would find that the lens with the least variation in the computed focal length is the "most ideal". It's an interesting way to define "good lens".

Comment: Couldn't a lens with positive distortion near the center and equal amount of negative distortion near the edges deliver correct focal length measurements with this method and still be a very bad lens?

Comment: I tried the thing that you offered, now my calculations satisfy the hardware that I'm using. Thank you very much again.

Comment: @enginkurutepe - in principle yes, but if you did the computation for several different fields of view and got the same answer you would know it's a good lens. With just two points you can't be sure.

Answer (score 0):

Your calculations assume an ideal pinhole system, which you obviously don't have here. Your wide angles lenses exhibit extreme distortions. Try to limit your measurements to the center of your optical system which seems to be distortion free. You should get results more inline with the focal lengths specified by the manufacturer.

EDIT: 
What Floris said above…